# Queries with MIN/MAX are much slower as subqueries than by themselves

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Consider a following query on a table with ~1M rows.
(The structure is in the end. TL;DR: it has `` UNIQUE KEY `max_filter` (`id_chat`, `id_device`, `id_message`) ``.)

```sql
SELECT MAX(`id_message`)
FROM `message_keys`
WHERE `id_chat` = 94609
    AND `id_device` = 26664
    AND `id_message` <= 238798
```

It runs almost instantly (around 1 ms) as expected.
When I modify it like this:

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT MAX(id_message)
    FROM message_keys
    WHERE message_keys.id_chat = 94609
        AND message_keys.id_device = devices.id
        AND message_keys.id_message <= 238798
) AS max
FROM devices
WHERE devices.id_user = 1
```

Assuming `user` 1 has 10 `device`s, I expect this to run 10–20 ms at most, but it takes unacceptable 500 to 1000 ms.

What seems to be the problem?

I am using MariaDB 10.1.23.

Explain:

```
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+-------------+
| id |    select_type     |    table     | type |        possible_keys         |    key     | key_len |          ref           | rows |    Extra    |             |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | devices      | ref  | id_user                      | id_user    |       4 | const                  |   10 | Using index |             |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | message_keys | ref  | PRIMARY,max_filter,id_device | max_filter |       8 | const,devices.id       |  520 | Using where | Using index |
+----+--------------------+--------------+------+------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+-------------+
```

`SHOW WARNINGS;` after `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`:

```
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1276 | Field or reference 'tukan.devices.id' of SELECT #2 was resolved in SELECT #1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| Note  | 1003 | select <expr_cache><`tukan`.`devices`.`id`>((select max(`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_message`) from `tukan`.`message_keys` where ((`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_chat` = 94609) and (`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_device` = `tukan`.`devices`.`id`) and (`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_message` <= 238798)))) AS `max` from `tukan`.`devices` where (`tukan`.`devices`.`id_user` = 1) |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Structures:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `message_keys` (
 `id_message` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `id_chat` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `id_from` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `id_device` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `key` blob NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('sent','delivered','read') CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_message`,`id_device`),
 UNIQUE KEY `max_filter` (`id_chat`,`id_device`,`id_message`),
 KEY `id_device` (`id_device`),
 CONSTRAINT `message_keys_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_message`) REFERENCES `messages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `message_keys_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_device`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `message_keys_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_chat`) REFERENCES `chats` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `devices` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_user` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `guid` binary(32) NOT NULL,
 `public_key` text CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `session_key` binary(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_session_home_key` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `is_locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `default_home_key` binary(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `time_created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `time_last_authorized` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `client_message_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
 KEY `id_session_home_key` (`id_session_home_key`),
 CONSTRAINT `devices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `devices_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_session_home_key`) REFERENCES `home_keys` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This:

```sql
SELECT MAX(`id_message`) AS `max`
FROM `devices`
LEFT JOIN `message_keys`
ON `message_keys`.`id_chat` = 94609
    AND `message_keys`.`id_device` = `devices`.`id`
    AND `message_keys`.`id_message` <= 238798
WHERE `devices`.`id_user` = 1
GROUP BY `devices`.`id`
```

Takes the same time (500–1000 ms).

```
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | select max(`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_message`) AS `max` from `tukan`.`devices` left join `tukan`.`message_keys` on(((`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_chat` = 94609) and (`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_device` = `tukan`.`devices`.`id`) and (`tukan`.`message_keys`.`id_message` <= 238798))) where (`tukan`.`devices`.`id_user` = 1) group by `tukan`.`devices`.`id` |
+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What if you do this via join and aggregation does it takes the same time ? Compare execution plans for both queries

Comment: and please show devices table structure.

Comment: The second query is a co-related subquery (DEPENDED SUBQUERY) in explain) which is very slow and badly optimized. You should indeed rewrite this query to a inner join approach which should outperform the co-related subquery if indexes are correctly used

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid done. The new query with `JOIN` I provided in the answer takes pretty much the same time.

Comment: The only possible solution I can think of now is to run a separate query for each device that a user has.

Comment: Could you do a `SHOW WARNINGS;` right after `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...` and add its output to your question?

Comment: @revo done. Shows 2 warnings/notes

Comment: Use an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Sub-queries can cause MySQL to create a temp table. Use a join to the devices table instead:

```
SELECT MAX(a.id_message)
FROM message_keys a
JOIN devices b
    ON a.device_id = b.id
WHERE a.id_chat = 94609
    AND a.id_device = 26664
    AND a.id_message <= 238798
    AND b.id_user = 1;
```

Comment: Your query would produce 1 row specifically for device 26664, and what I need is a MAX value for each device that user 1 has. Basically I need the same output that second query gives.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(mk.id_message)
        FROM message_keys mk
        WHERE mk.id_chat = 94609 AND
              mk.id_device = d.id AND
              mk.id_message <= 238798
       ) as max
FROM devices d
WHERE d.id_user = 1;
```

The optimal indexes are `devices(id_user, id)` and `message_keys(id_device, id_chat, id_message)`.

In particular, your first query can choose any of the three single column indexes for the query.  For the second, it has to use the one on `(device_id)`, and that is probably not the best index for the query.

Comment: So I added `(id_user, id)` and `(id_device, id_chat, id_message)` to devices and `message_keys` respectively and made sure the query uses them, but nothing changed, it still takes 500 ms.

Comment: @jlblca9l_kpblca . . . I suspect that one of the devices has a whole lot of messages, then.

Comment: All of the devices have the same amount of 163118.
In fact, executing a `UNION` of 10 separate queries for each device is about twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Whats happens if you group on your key?

```
SELECT (
SELECT MAX(id_message)
FROM message_keys
WHERE message_keys.id_chat = 94609
    AND message_keys.id_device = devices.id
    AND message_keys.id_message <= 238798 GROUP BY 
message_keys.id_chat,message_keys.id_device ,message_keys.id_message
) AS max
FROM devices
WHERE devices.id_user = 1
```

Comment: It returns an error "Subquery returns more than 1 row" as expected.